# How do I include Lucene for App Engine in my existing Project

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, lucene

I was referred to [Lucene for App Engine (LAE)](https://code.google.com/p/luceneappengine/) as a more robust replacement for the Search Api. But I am not sure how to incorporate LAE into my existing project. My existing project does not use maven. I am not really sure how to get started even though seemingly there is a set of instructions. I am using eclipse. What's the **for Dummy** version? I already tried copying the zip from git and then import project into eclipse: that didn't work. Then I tried copying the source files into a package in my own project: that didn't work either. How do I go about getting this thing to compile with my Project? I wish it were just a jar. Anyway, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than including Lucene directly, I would highly recommend looking at spinning up an instance of elasticsearch if you're looking to replace the search api: https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

Note, that Elasticsearch is backed by Lucene but hides the complexity of Lucene behind a very rich API.

Comment: I am not looking for a paid service if I can roll one out myself. I just need to know how to add the project in the provided link to my own project. But thanks.

Comment: Elasticsearch is opensource. You can deploy it to compute engine and interact with it on appengine.